# Any efficient workaround to extract key phrase from given sentences with TF-IDF scheme?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, text-extraction

I am trying to extract a key phrase from given sentence with TF-IDF schema. To do that, I tried to find out candidate word or candidate phrase in the sentence, then use get frequent word in the sentence. However, when I introduced new `CFG` rule for finding possible key phrases in the sentence, I have error.

Here is my script:

```
rm_punct=re.compile('[{}]'.format(re.escape(string.punctuation)))
stop_words=set(stopwords.words('english'))

def get_cand_words(sent, cand_type='word', remove_punct=False):
    candidates=list()
    sent=rm_punct.sub(' ', sent)
    tokenized=word_tokenize(sent)
    tagged_words=pos_tag(tokenized)
    if cand_type=='word':
        pos_tag_patt=tags = set(['JJ', 'JJR', 'JJS', 'NN', 'NNP', 'NNS', 'NNPS'])
        tagged_words=chain.from_iterable(tagged_words)
        for word, tag in enumerate(tagged_words):
            if tag in pos_tag_patt and word not in stop_words:
                candidates.append(word)

    elif cand_type == 'phrase':
        grammar = r'KT: {(<JJ>* <NN.*>+ <IN>)? <JJ>* <NN.*>+}'
        chunker = RegexpParser(grammar)
        all_tag = chain.from_iterable([chunker.parse(tag) for tag in tagged_words])
        for key, group in groupby(all_tag, lambda tag: tag[2] != 'O'):
            candidate = ' '.join([word for (word, pos, chunk) in group])
            if key is True and candidate not in stop_words:
                candidates.append(candidate)
    else:
        print("return word or phrase as target phrase")
    return candidates
```

Here is the error that raised by python:

```
sentence_1="Hillary Clinton agrees with John McCain by voting to give George Bush the benefit of the doubt on Iran."

sentence_2="The United States has the highest corporate tax rate in the free world"

get_cand_words(sent=sentence_1, cand_type='phrase', remove_punct=False)

ValueError: chunk structures must contain tagged tokens or trees
```

I inspired the above code based on extracting key phrases from long text paragraph, my goal is want to find a unique key phrase in the given sentence, but the above implementation doesn't work well.

How can I fix this value error? How can I make above implementation works for extracting key phrase in the given sentence or sentence list? Any better idea to make this happen? any more thoughts? Thanks

**Goal**:

I want to find out a most relevant noun-adjective phrase or compound noun-adjective phrase from given sentence. How can I get this done in python? Anyone knows how to make this happen? Thanks in advance

Answer (score -3):

Can you try with this code?

```
   rm_punct=re.compile('[{}]'.format(re.escape(string.punctuation)))
   stop_words=set(stopwords.words('english'))

   def get_cand_words(sent, cand_type='word', remove_punct=False):
    import nltk
    candidates=list()
    sent=rm_punct.sub(' ', sent)
    tokenized=word_tokenize(sent)
    tagged_words=pos_tag(tokenized)
    if cand_type=='word':
        pos_tag_patt=tags = set(['JJ', 'JJR', 'JJS', 'NN', 'NNP', 'NNS', 'NNPS'])
        tagged_words=chain.from_iterable(tagged_words)
        for word, tag in enumerate(tagged_words):
            if tag in pos_tag_patt and word not in stop_words:
                candidates.append(word)

    elif cand_type == 'phrase':
        grammar = r'KT: {(<JJ>* <NN.*>+ <IN>)? <JJ>* <NN.*>+}'
        chunker = RegexpParser(grammar)
        tagged_words=nltk.pos_tag_sents(nltk.word_tokenize(text) for text in nltk.sent_tokenize(sent))
        all_tag = list(chain.from_iterable(nltk.chunk.tree2conlltags(chunker.parse(tagged_word)) for tagged_word in tagged_words))
        for key, group in groupby(all_tag, lambda tag: tag[2] != 'O'):
            candidate = ' '.join([word for (word, pos, chunk) in group])
            if key is True and candidate not in stop_words:
                candidates.append(candidate)
    else:
        print("return word or phrase as target phrase")
    return candidates
```

Comment: I didn't see any significant update from your answer, pretty much same with my original post, your code doesn't work, can you remove your answer?

Comment: @Jerry - I made changes inside  elif block. tagged_words and all_tag assignment lines are changed.

Comment: This code is working perfectly fine for me.  I am getting ['Hillary Clinton', 'John McCain', 'George Bush', 'benefit', 'doubt on Iran'] as output.

Comment: above code is not okay with me when I choose the parameter `cand_type` as `phrase`, and I have this error: Currently, NLTK pos_tag only supports English and Russian (i.e. lang='eng' or lang='rus'), why? what's your setup then? Plus could you update your workable code as well?